# Open Source Operating System

Tags: init

Open Source Operating System
A server or computer;
A computer taken init 6 mode resets itself continuously. How to get to the init init 5 or 2 mode.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you saying you set the default runlevel to 6 and want to know how to set it back?

Also, I'm curious where you got "Open Source Operating System A server or computer" from.

Comment: Sound like an assignment dumped verbatim

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I disagree; I think an assignment would be more clearly written than that.

Comment: Is a little synthetic question,but I understand you probably has put the runlevel 6 as default runlevel,if use the standard init run from cd,or from single user mode editing grub ,and then edit /etc/inittab,put defaultrunlevel to 3 o 5

Comment: It's http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317387/ again.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear...

If you're running a Unix-like operating-system - like Linux or *BSD - which uses `init` as the ancestor of all other processes, you should **never** set the *default runlevel* to 0 = halted system, or 6 = reboot system.

If you have specified one of the above as the default runlevel in */etc/inittab*; you should boot your computer from a **disc or USB**, mount the root-partition of your installed OS (on the harddrive), and edit its /etc/inittab (eg. /mnt/etc/inittab) to a more suitable run-level.  (If it's an old-style inittab, I think the line is "ri:6" - presumably for "runlevel initial".)

Comment: Open Source Operating System

A server or computer

init 6 mode into a computer,
Reboot itself constantly.
 
init 2 or init 5 to get into the mode.

What needs to be done